# Express.js : POST data sent as KEY ONLY in my req.body object

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, reactjs, express

I am currently having an issue with my POST request.

I have a simple function that is responsible of sending data to my server using AJAX.

```
handleSubmit(event) {

var http = new XMLHttpRequest(); // object allwos us to make http requests 

//Lets make a request
http.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/register", true);//set up the request for us: type of request we want, where we want the data from, do we want it to be sync or async?

http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

//each time the ready state changes on the http object, it will fire this function. 
http.onreadystatechange = function(){
    console.log(http); // lets see the ready state changing... 

    //once the ready state hits 4(request is completed) && status is 200 (which is okay), lets do something with data.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){

    }else{
      console.log('Error: ' + http.status); // An error occurred during the request.
    }
}

let user = {
  email: "john@gmail.com"
};

http.send(JSON.stringify(user));
}
```

My server side code is pretty simple and contains a POST end point.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

//Body Parser Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req);
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Now, once handleSubmit fires, the req body of my object becomes the following:

```
{ '{"email":"john@gmail.com"}': '' }
```

I am very confused and I'm not quite sure how to proceed.

Thank you!

Comment: Just one hint which comes to my mind. Remove Json.stringfy()

Comment: I tried the same code on my front, it sends the body just right, so, mostly a back-end issue,try passing `{type: "application/json"}` as an argument for `express.json()`, and make sure it's the same in the front

Answer (score 2):

Everything seems to be good,
You have to declare the Header as **json**,

```
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to run this, I've learned a lot.
You are sending json object as a data, but content-type is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for `json` data content-type needs to be `application/json` but somehow it's not working for me.

I made some tests and this is what I ended

```js
const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = "http://localhost:3000/register";

const json = JSON.stringify(user);

http.open("POST", url, true);

// In order to sent JSON you need to set this, but somehow it's not working
// http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
// http.send(JSON.stringify(user));

// In order to work with this type app, you need to send data as a string like below
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.send('id=1&isAdmin=false&email=john@gmail.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is still relevant, I had similar issue with the parsing. Try adding this:

```
app.use(express.json());
```

to your code to enable built-in express body parser that works specifically with json AND changing 'Content-type' to 'application/json'. Right now you're trying to parse request.body of json type as a urlencoded, that's where the new object with request body as key comes from.

Answer (score -1):

Try `{email: "name@gmail.com", id:1 }`